# Open Photos app programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiapplication

Is it possible to launch the "Photos" application from an iPhone app? Similar to launching mail?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Photos app doesn't appear to register any URL schemes that other apps can use. There's a pretty well-established pattern in other system apps (e.g. Safari) of “saving an image” resulting in that image being placed in the user's camera roll; I'd recommend just sticking with that expected behavior, and perhaps using an alert to direct the user to look there for your app's exported image.

Comment: saving and alerting works already fine. so i think i just have to tell the client we don't need the "as Backround" button anymore ;)

Comment: Was this added in newer APIs perhaps? I'm looking for similar solution and would like to know if it's possible.