# Open iPhone Camera Roll app programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

There are plenty of tutorials on how to access the camera roll with a picker view, but what about closing the app, and loading the camera roll, ie. leaving the app altogether to access the camera roll.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: You can start other apps using URLs. However the Photos app doesn't seem to register any URLs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187872/iphone-open-photos-app-programmatically

Comment: ok, thank you. Guess I gotta go back to square 1 lol

Comment: Why do you want this? Provided picker view doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: Because we're trying to push our app through quickly, and didn't want to spend the time and money working on it this way :p.  But, not choice now