# iPhone - How to launch photos app like default camera app?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm developing iOS 3rd party camera app.
I really want to make "previewing function" like default camera app below
I've tried UIImagePickerController but, it is not what I want

[image]
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Photos app programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187872/open-photos-app-programmatically)

Comment: not getting the question,u are making ur own custom camera and u want to show these preview from Photos app right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not what i'm looking for..

Comment: @muku exactly right!